# Where does Yajurveda have "karpūragauraṁ karuṇāvatāraṁ....bhavaṁ bhavānīsahitaṁ namāmi" verse?

Tags: shiva, yajur-veda, shloka

One of the most famous slokas used for Lord Shiva (Rudra) during *arti* or prayer is

> कर्पूरगौरं करुणावतारम् 
>   संसारसारं भुजगेन्द्रहारम् | 
>   सदा वसन्तं हृदयारविन्दे
>   भवं भवानीसहितं नमामि ||
>
> karpūragauraṁ karuṇāvatāraṁ
>   sansārsāram bhujagendrahāram | 
>   sadāvasantaṁ hṛdayāravinde
>   bhavaṁ bhavānīsahitaṁ namāmi ||

[Translation](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=BmAoDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT189&lpg=PT189&dq=karpoora%20gauram%20yajurveda&source=bl&ots=BfdfyvalnY&sig=jt61IF30cND_qrkqYExdYGn3j2Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigms6eu7DVAhUHNo8KHcvjD58Q6AEIUjAI#v=onepage&q=karpoora%20gauram%20yajurveda&f=false):

> I bow to Shiva along with Shakti (Parvati),  who resides ever in the
>   lotus of my heart,  Who is the color of camphor, who is filled with
>   kindness,  who is the support of the world and who wears a snake as a 
>   garland.

This verse has word "**bhujagendrahāram**" which means the one who has Lord of serpents as ornament. This is interesting because i think Rudra in Vedas is not mentioned with Serpents (I can be wrong too).

Many sites on internet including [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karpuragauram_Karunavtaaram) say this verse is from **Yajurveda** and wiki cites Devichand's translation of [Yajurveda](https://archive.org/details/yajurveda029670mbp) but I couldn't find it in that book. Also, I couldn't find it through [Digital Corpus of Sanskrit](http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=dictionary&limit=20&first_letter=k&text_id=0&limit=20&page=139).

Where exactly  Yajurveda has this verse? Is it from Krishna Yajurveda or Shukla Yajurveda? If from Samhita, who is Rishi and what is meter for this verse? I think Devata must be **Rudra**, but also mention Devata for this Mantra. If this is from Brahmana or Aranyaka, mention exact verse location.

**Note**: I want to know exact location of this verse. Please don't provide some external site which says this verse can be found in Yajurveda.

Comment: I feel its not at all part of any Veda. because the language clearly suggests so. Further if it is vedic then it would be chanted in swara which is also not the case.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Even i'm not sure of it. I think it might be present in Aranyaka or Brahmana or some lost Sakha of Yajurveda. But since is said it is from Yajurveda, it might be present in Yajurveda.

Comment: in any shakha if it was there it will be clearly known from its language. i am almost sure that its not from main vedic literature. could be a later day upanishad. Further, it is also debatable if aranyakas etc constitute the veda.

Comment: yajurveda brahmana is mixed with samhita itself its not separate.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi ok. I have also included Aranyaka and Brahmana (though some believe they don't constitute Vedas). But Shukla Yajurveda has them separately.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Can you please help find the answer of this question as I also have the same question and this question is still unanswered. In the internet, same old is mentioned that it is from Yajurveda. But ofcourse from the comments you are confident that it is not from Vedas.

Comment: @Ram Because the language doesn't look vedic but of later origin...

Comment: It is not from any veda. It is a sloka written by Goshwami Tulsidas.

Comment: "bhavānīsahitaṁ - alongwith Bhavani".  It may not be from Veda.  It might have been taken from Shiva Purana or from other Puranas or written by some scholar@TheDestroyer

Answer (score 7):

This verse is not present in the Yajurveda.

This verse is a present in a commentary to a verse in the so-called “Brhihad Brahma Nitya Karma Sammuchya” (see page 51 of this book [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.327447/page/n63)). This book and many others (for example this [one](https://archive.org/details/ldpd_8960570_000/page/n1)) is (was) a north/central Indian equivalent to the current versions of Sandhyavandan type of post-Vedic practices that are still popular in south India.

This book is a collection of cherry-picked verses from the Saṃhitā and provided with self-made verses eulogizing Shiva and others. The verse in your question is one of such self-made verses and attributed to the Saṃhitā.

Probably, the verse in question is attributed to Yajurveda because it was popularized in the books that claim to present "Nitya karma" as per Yajur Veda!

As it is in vogue even today the ardent devotees of Purāṇic protagonists like Shiva, Rama, Krishna have a proclivity to marry verses of the post-Vedic period with some or the other Saṃhitā.

Such practices are desperate attempts to portray their beliefs as Vedic as it provides an element of credence of having a continuation from the antiquity.

Unfortunately, for these ardent devotees, such post-Vedic verses do not match with the morphology of the Saṃhitā!

Comment: Are you suggesting that Shiva is not the Vedic Rudra?

Comment: @LazyLubber  Puranic Shiva is not Vedic Rudra. I have hinted at in my answers to some other questions (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36197/are-the-11-rudras-mentioned-in-the-vedas/36791#36791) . Also, Puranic Brahma is not Vedic Prajapati https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/are-the-vedic-gods-prajapati-and-brahma-the-same/37059#37059

Comment: Ok, is Puranic Vishnu, Vedic Vishnu? I am genuinely asking. It is interesting to meet people with different views.

Comment: Please remove the last 3 paragraphs. They aren't relevant to the question. Good answer@965167

Comment: @LazyLubber No Puranic Vishnu is not Vedic Vishnu. Try to understand what rtam is.

Comment: Good answer @user965167. The differences between The Puranic and Vedic deities (in terms of their portrayal, character, the personification) is something I have repeatedly observed for long. In fact that is one of the basis for my explanations for many seemingly conflicting accounts in The Puranas and religious texts of the latter period. 
I liked your crisp and concise answer without compromising the core idea.

Comment: To add some comments for what it's worth - there are indications, and basis to argue that Puranic deities evolved from their Vedic counterparts over time. There is good amount of literature and research that support this view (I need time to compile them). 
Many factors contributed to this evolution, and one can write a book on that aspect. For example, take a look at Mahadev Chakravarthi's book - "The Concept of Rudra Shiva through the Ages"
https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Concept_of_Rudra_%C5%9Aiva_Through_the_A.html?id=yMFwMHH4HzMC
Part of the reason is simply the human nature.