# Is brahma born from navel of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, brahma, birth

We all have seen paintings of Vishnu where Brahma is shown to sprout out of the navel of Vishnu.

What is the truth behind Brahma emerging from the navel of Vishnu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How were the Trimurthi born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born)

Comment: Prajapati of the Vedas is self-manifested Brahman.  As "Brahma" itihasapuranas assign him various births.  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/are-the-vedic-gods-prajapati-and-brahma-the-same

Comment: This so obviously a duplicate of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the history of Brahma's birth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36499/what-is-the-history-of-brahmas-birth)

Comment: Why isn't this question getting closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Different views can exists.

### Shiva Purāṇa:-

As per Shiva Purana Brahma was created by Shiva from his right side, but was made to come out of the Lotus from Vishnu's navel, as per Shiva's maya.

> Verse 2.1.7.4-6
>
> Exerting himself as before, Śiva, the great lord, with Pārvatī as his
> better half created me from His right limb.
>
> O sage, having deluded me with His illusion immediately, Śiva in the
> course of His sport, produced me through the umbilical lotus of Viṣṇu.
>
> Thus it was that I came to be known as Lotus-born and conceived in a
> golden womb. I had four faces, red complexion.
>
> English Translation by J.L Shastri.

Thus, as per Shaivite view, Shiva is the Creator of Brahma.

---

#### As per Mahabharata

> [Section CCLXX](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7553.html), Draupadi-harana Parva, Vana Parva
>
> The Supreme Spirit has three conditions. In the form of Brahma, he is
> the Creator, and in the form of Vishnu he is the Preserver, and in his
> form as Rudra, he is the Destroyer of the Universe!.
>
> English Translation by K.M. Ganguli

So, it's the one-same Supreme deity who's manifesting as per the role required for the universe.

---

Similarly other texts describe Brahma as unborn, yet self-born, unmanifested, etc. Depending upon sectarian literature.

There can't be a conclusive answer, for different texts will have different answers and interpretations by people, for Brahmâ's or any other deities origin.

Comment: Why is this not accepted? This is a nice answer?

Answer (score 0):

This symbolism of creator Brahma is well explained as part of Dhuruva Stuti and Prahalada Stuti  occuring in shrimad Bhagvada Mahapurana

Narasimha stuti by Bhaktha Prahalad
(*seventh Skanda, ninth Adhyaya of Srimad Bhagavada Mahapurana*)

> **tasyai thE vapu: idam nija kAla sakthyA
> sanchOditha prakriti dharmiNa Aatma ghooDam/
> ambasi anantha sayanAth viramath samAdhE:
> nabhEhr abhooth svakaNikAth vaDavath mahA abjam(33)**
> " You, after the yOga nidra, get up from the deep slumber and begin to
> create the universe again i.e. you exhibit yourself again. Then, from your
> divine navel springs up a lotus flower, just as a Banyan tree rises up from a
> small seed. The lotus flower is a very big one"
> **tath sambhava: kavi: athO anyath apasyamAnah:
> tvAm beejam Aatmani thatham sva bahir vichinthya/
> na avindaath abda satham apsu nimajjamAnah:
> jAtha ankurE katham athah: upalabEda beejam(34)**
> " From that flower, Lord Brahma was born. Then, Brahma did not see
> anything except himself and that flower. He was curious to know how he and
> the flower came. He went round and round. No success. Then, for full one
> hundred Brahma-years he dived into the praLaya ocean. Even then he could
> not see the Lord who was the cause of that lotus flower. This, however, is
> nothing strange. How can a seed be again observed when the seed has
> sprouted?"
> **sa tvat AatmayOnir athi vismitha aasritha abjam
> kAlEna theevra tapasA parisuddha bhAva:/
> tvam Aatman Eesa! Bhuvi gandham iva athi sookshmabhootha
> indriyAsayam ayam vithatham dadarsa(35)**
> " Then, that Brahma performed Tapas for a very long time and became purified in mind. Then he saw you, Oh! Lord!, all pervading, in a subtle fashion, just as one feels smell in the earth. How were you then? You were all exhibiting yourself in all your Bhuta-sookshma and Indriyas (senses). Such are you. Oh! Lord!"
> **yEvam sahasra vadhana angri sirah: kara OorunAsAsya
> karNa nayana AbharaNa AayudhAdyAm/
> mAyamayam sad upalakshaNa sannivEsam
> drishTvA mahA purusham Aapa mudham virinchih:( 36)**
> " That same Brahma then saw your awe-inspiring form full of mAya, with thousands of faces, mouths, ears, hands, thighs, noses etc. and realized that you are the one mahApurusha and derived immense pleasure"
> *(English Translation by Sri
> P.N.Krishnaswamy Iyengar)*

**Dhuruva Stuti** - shloka 3
(*12 verses of Dhuruva stuti is in the 4th skanda of Shrimad Bhagavada Mahapurana*)

> **tvad-dattayA vayunayedam acashTa viSvam
> supta-prabhuddha iva nAtha bhavat-prapannaH /
> tasyApavargya-SaraNaM tava pAda-mUlaM
> vismaryate kRta-vidA katham Arta-bandho**
> O my master, Lord Brahmā is fully surrendered unto You. In the beginning You gave him knowledge, and thus he could see and understand the entire universe, just as a person awakens from sleep and visualizes his immediate duties. You are the only shelter of all persons who desire liberation, and You are the friend of all who are distressed. How, therefore, can a learned person who has perfect knowledge ever forget You?(Translation vedabase.io)

> It was You who gave the divine sight to the Creator Himself to recall how He did the Creation in the previous cycle. Let us note here that the Hindu theory of Creation and Dissolution is a phenomenon of recurring cycles.  Once Creation starts it is Brahma's day. When everything dissolves in the Infinite Absolute the day-time of Brahma is over and Brahma 'sleeps' as it were. The next morning there is another day of manifestation, that is, creation - which will end up in Brahma's evening by another dissolution. Each such day of Brahma is called one kalpa. On the beginning of every such day, it is the Lord that has to 'sanctify' Brahma with the necessary spiritual power to create the universe.
> *(Explanation by prof. V . Krishnamurthy)*

Answer (score 0):

**Mahabharata, Anusashana Parva.:**

> *"Thou art he that hadst created from thy right side the Grandsire Brahma, the Creator of all things. Thou art he that hadst created from thy left side Vishnu for protecting the Creation. Thou art that puissant Lord who didst create Rudra (the destroyer deity Kalagni-Rudra from thy heart) when the end of the Yuga came and when the Creation was once more to be dissolved” (MBH 13:14:183).*

**Sri Shiva Purana 2.1:7:4-6.:**

> *Exerting himself as before (i.e.,Pouring nectar on his Right Limb), Śiva, the great lord, with Pārvatī as his better half created me from His right limb.
> O sage, having deluded me with His illusion immediately, Śiva in the course of His sport, produced me through the umbilical lotus of Viṣṇu.
> Thus it was that I came to be known as Lotus-born and conceived in a golden womb.*

**Sri Shiva Purana 2.1:1:9.:**

> *64. In the Kalpa called Pādma, Pitāmaha (Brahmā) will be born as your (Vishnu's) son. Then you will see me. The lotus-born Brahmā shall also see me.*

**Here is an excerpt from Sri [Linga Purana](http://hinduphilosophypuranas.blogspot.com/2012/01/linga-purana-skanda-purana-kartika.html?m=1) which should explain how Brahma became son of Vishnu.**

> ***"Lomaharshana recounted the following story.***
>
> *Many years ago, at the end of a cycle of destruction, there was water everywhere in the universe and the universe was shrouded in darkness. Vishnu slept on the water in his form of Narayana.
> Brahma discovered Vishnu sleeping thus and woke him up. Failing to recognize Vishnu, he asked, “Who are you and what are you doing here?”
> Vishnu woke up and noticed Brahma standing there. He smiled and said, “How are you, Brahma? Is everything well with my son?’
> “How dare you call me your son?’ demanded Brahma. “I am Brahma, the lord of everything. I am the creator of the universe. How dare anyone call me his son?”
> “You seem to have forgotten everything,” said Vishnu. “I am Vishnu and you were born from me. That is the reason why I addressed you as my son.”
> Brahma did not accept this and started to argue with Vishnu
> “But why did Vishnu address Brahma as his son?” asked the sages. “Please explain that.”
> **Lomaharshana told them the following story from the kalpa known as padma kalpa.**
> At the time of the destruction that came at the end of the earlier kalpa, there was water everywhere in the universe and Vishnu slept on this water. Vishnu felt slightly bored. So he made a gigantic lotus sprout out of his navel and started to play with it. The stalk of the lotus was made of diamonds and it shone with radiance like the sun.
> While Vishnu was thus playing with the lotus , Brahma appeared.
> “Who are you?” asked Brahma. “What are you doing here?”
> “I am Vishnu,” replied Vishnu. “I am the lord of everything. But who are you and where have you come from?”
> “I am Brahma,” responded Brahma. “I am the lord of everything in the universe. Every object that will be created in the universe is already present in embryonic form, inside my body. If you don’t believe me, why don’t you enter my stomach and see for yourself?”
> Vishnu entered Brahma’s body through the mouth. He marvelled to discover the fourteen regions (lokas) of the univerise and the beings who would populate them all, inside Brahma’s stomach. Vishnu wandered around for a thousand yeards, but could find no end to the vast expanse of Brahma’s stomach. Finally, he emerged through the mouth and told Brahma, “I am completely bowled over by what I have seen. But I can also show you wonders. There are many worlds inside my body as well. Enter for yourself and see.”
> Brahma agreed to this and entered Vishnu’s body through the mouth. Inside Vishnu’ stomach, he saw many worlds. He wandered around for a thousand years, but could not find the extremities of the stomach. Meanwhile, Vishnu had closed all the points of exit and Brahma could find no way of coming out. He eventualy came out through the lotus that sprouted out of Vishnu’s navel and seated himself on the lotus. Since padma means lotus and yoni means place of birth, Brahma thenceforth came to be known as Padmayoni. And since Brahma emerged out of Vishnu’s body, he came to be regarded as Visnu’s son. While Brahma was thus seated on the lotus, Shiva arrived. Such was the speed of Shiva’s arrival that tidal waves were created in the water. The lotus started to tremble and Brahma was showered with drops of water.
> “Stop shaking the lotus so,” said Brahma. “You are scaring me.”
> “Who speaks from my navel?’ asked Vishnu. “And why do you sound so angry?”
> “I am Brahma,” replied Brahma. “I have every right to be angry. Don’t you remember? You had entered my body and had marvelled at the worlds I had shown you there. You had then asked me to enter your body. But once I had done that, you had closed all the points of entry so that I had not been able to get out. I had to emerge through the lotus and now now seated on it. Apart from your earlier transgression, you have now started to shake the lotus. Why should I not be angry?”
> “Please pardon me,” replied Vishnu. “I had no desire to offend you by closing all the points of exit. I merely wished to play with you for a while. Please forgive me. And as a token of your friendship, please grant me the boon that you will henceforth be known as my son. "*

**Sri Shiva Purana 3:11:40.:**

> *40. You (Vishnu) are Prakṛti and Rudra is Puruṣa. The seed is deposited in you. The five-faced Brahmā was born of your umbilical lotus.*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..